# How should we open external google maps app from react-native app to get the result in a response?

Tags: google-maps, react-native

My application wants to capture the address of the user but we don't want to integrate map component inside our react-native app.

What we want is to open the external app with the query & get the result in the response.

For example startActivityForResult in android, which opens other application for the result.

Does google map have such function?

Comment: I also found one supported way of getting results from map but it is deprecated [PlacePicker](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/placepicker)

Answer (score 0):

you can use Linking in react native to open the google maps

`import {Linking} from 'react-native'`
then add the following line to place where you want to open google maps

`Linking.openURL("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps");`